# WordPress TwentyTen menu: how to CSS-select sub-menus in a specific position?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, twenty-ten-theme

I'm styling the top menu of the WordPress TwentyTen theme.

I want all sub-menus of the first menu item to be 200px wide,

all submenus of the second menu item to be 250px wide,

and all submenus of the third menu item to be 300px wide.

For example, the menu has the following structure:

**ABOUT**

- Mission
- History
- People

**SERVICES**

- Service1
- Service2
- Service3

**PRODUCTS**

- Product1
- Product2
- Product3

I want all items under ABOUT to be 200px wide, all items under SERVICES to be 250px wide, and all items under PRODUCTS to be 300px wide.

How can I select them in WordPress using only CSS? (Considering that the menu is generated dynamically and the header only has wp_nav_menu command?)

Comment: Please include the code you have trouble with.

Comment: That would be several pages of code. :-(

Comment: Sorry if im mis-understanding your question, but could you go into wp-header.php, give each list element a class and then style it?

Comment: Thank you Liam. Those elements are not in the header though. The header just has this: wp_nav_menu. But you nailed the very essence of my question: how do I SELECT those elements to give each of them class? Could you expand on that please?

Comment: How are you generating the menus? If they're custom menus (as set up using Appearance/Menus in the admin interface) then you can add CSS classes to each sub-menu -- you'll have change "Screen Options" on the menu admin page to tick "Show advanced menu properties/CSS Classes".

Comment: Thank you Matt, that's exactly what I do, but it doesn't work. With top level menus, the classes added to <a> tags, apparently. With bottom level menus, the classes seem to be added to the <li> tags, and as a result, nothing happens when I add the class. But your reply is the closest to the issue, so far. How can I add that class to the a tag instead of the li tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using custom menu structure defined under the Appearance/Menus admin interface page, you can add CSS classes to each submenu item from there.

Go to the admin page, then choose "Screen Options" at the top. Under there, you'll find a series of tickboxes under "Show advanced menu properties". One of those is "CSS Classes". Once you've ticked that box, you should find that each of your submenu options panes now has a "CSS Classes (optional)" textbox where you can add one or more classes.

Once that's done, you can style away to your heart's content...

Comment: Thank you Matt, that's exactly what I do, but it doesn't work. With top level menus, the classes added to <a> tags, apparently. With bottom level menus, the classes seem to be added to the <li> tags, and as a result, nothing happens when I add the class. But your reply is the closest to the issue, so far. How can I add that class to the a tag instead of the li tag?

Comment: @Dimitri Do you need to? You could target the `<a>` tags with CSS like this: `li.whateverclass > a { color: red }` (That would match only `<a>` tags that were immediate children of `<li>` tags with class `whateverclass`). If you wish to target both the types you see with the same rule, you could use `li.whateverclass > a, a.whateverclass { color: red }`, for example.

Comment: YES Matt! Thank you very much! I just figured out the same thing a couple of seconds ago and was about to post it to you but you beat me to that! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a css selector that matches each level. Like this:

```
#access ul {
   width: 200px;
}
#access ul ul {
   width: 250px;
}
#access ul ul ul {
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bengt, but this is not quite what I was asking about. I guess I expressed it not very coherently. I do not want different levels to have different widths. I want the same level of submenu to have different width, depending on the position of the higher level item. Please take a look at the edited question. Would be grateful for further advice from you.